# How to hide text after hover using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to hide text after hover on section. I have to display full circle image and after hover to hide "Profile name" and "Designation".It should be display only image and visit profile button.i am getting below result.Would you help me in this?
[image]
**Need result like this**

[image]

```css
.white-color-bg
{
    background-color:  #ffffff ;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
     position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.white-color-bg:hover .item-overlay.right {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.teacher-circle img
{
    width: 135px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.cursor-pointer
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* fix text transition issue for .left and .right but need to overwrite left and right properties in .right */
  width: 100%; 
  
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}
.item-overlay.right {
  right: 200%;
  left: -100%;
}
.item-overlay a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left:-50px;

}

.white-color-bg h2
{
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    
}

.white-color-bg h3
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    color: #e74c3c !important;


}
.white-color-bg h2, .white-color-bg h3
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 0;
}

.btn-profile
{
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 05px 20px;
    border-radius: 05px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    z-index: 3;
}

.btn-profile:hover
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color: #e74c3c; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
              <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2" >
              <div class="item-overlay right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-profile">visit profile</a>
              </div>
              <h2>Profile name</h2>
              <h3>Designation</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can set the `visibility` of the `h2` and `h3` elements to `hidden` on hover of the `.white-color-bg` element. Try this:

```css
.white-color-bg:hover h2,
.white-color-bg:hover h3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
.white-color-bg {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.white-color-bg:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
.white-color-bg:hover .item-overlay.right {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.white-color-bg:hover h2,
.white-color-bg:hover h3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.teacher-circle img {
  width: 135px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* fix text transition issue for .left and .right but need to overwrite left and right properties in .right */
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}
.item-overlay.right {
  right: 200%;
  left: -100%;
}
.item-overlay a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.white-color-bg h2 {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.white-color-bg h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 400;
  color: #e74c3c !important;
}
.white-color-bg h2,
.white-color-bg h3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 0;
}
.btn-profile {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 05px 20px;
  border-radius: 05px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-profile:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
        <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2">
        <div class="item-overlay right">
          <a href="#" class="btn-profile">visit profile</a>
        </div>
        <h2>Profile name</h2>
        <h3>Designation</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr.Rory, My half issue got resolved but how can i display full image.I am taking about that circle image

Comment: I have added one image in question.Please check that.I need like that.If i remove "overflow: hidden;" from ".white-color-bg" than it works but i don't want to remove that..Please help me

Comment: You can do that buy changing the `bottom` property on hover. I updated my answer for you

Comment: Thanks for reply again Mr.Rory.I replace my image in question.Hope you can understand now what i am asking.

Comment: Ah, you need to set `overflow: visible` in that case. See my update

Comment: Same image i need before hover.I don't want to cut that circle image.Please check my image.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap the content to hide in a div element

```
<div id="hide" class="center">
   <h2>Profile name</h2>
   <h3>Designation</h3>
</div>
```

give opacity:0; to the #hide element in css

```
#hide{
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;

}
```

place the img outside of the parent element

```
 <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2" class="center">


<div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
```

change **position:absolute;**
and adjust the **top and bottom** to place it: (**Use Percentage!**)

To center the element use **.center** class

```
.center{
            left:50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>


<body>
    <style>
        .white-color-bg {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            height:200px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 2%;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        
        .white-color-bg:hover .item-overlay.right {
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        
        img {
            width: 135px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            background: #fff;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 50px;
            
        }
            
        .center{
            left:50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        .cursor-pointer {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .item-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            /* fix text transition issue for .left and .right but need to overwrite left and right properties in .right */
            width: 100%;
            -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
            -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
            transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
        }
        
        .item-overlay.right {
            right: 200%;
            left: -100%;
        }
        
        .item-overlay a {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 30px;
            margin-left: -50px;
        }
        
        .white-color-bg h2 {
            font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
            font-size: 400;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .white-color-bg h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
            font-size: 400;
            color: #e74c3c !important;
        }
        
        .white-color-bg h2,
        .white-color-bg h3 {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 20px;
            line-height: 0;
            color: #000;
            z-index: 0;
        }
        
        .btn-profile {
            border: 2px solid #ffffff;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: absolute;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            z-index: 2;
          left:60%;
        }
      
        
        .btn-profile:hover {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            color: #e74c3c;
        }
        .white-color-bg:hover > #hide {
            opacity:0;
        }
        #hide{
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            
        }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2" class="center">
                    
                <div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
                    
                    
                    <div class="item-overlay right">
                        
                        <a href="#" class="btn-profile center">visit profile</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hide" class="center">
                        <h2>Profile name</h2>
                        <h3>Designation</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A little description of what the issue is an how this solves it would help the OP a lot more than just dumping code.

Comment: Thank for reply Mr.Nishaanth. How can i display full image of circle?

Comment: I edited the code. Thanks Rory for the suggestion. I am new to stackoverflow :-)

Comment: add the image outside of its parent container

Answer (score 0):

```css
.white-color-bg
{
    background-color:  #ffffff ;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
     position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.white-color-bg:hover h2,
.white-color-bg:hover h3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.white-color-bg:hover .item-overlay.right {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.teacher-circle img
{
    width: 135px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.cursor-pointer
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* fix text transition issue for .left and .right but need to overwrite left and right properties in .right */
  width: 100%; 
  
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}
.item-overlay.right {
  right: 200%;
  left: -100%;
}
.item-overlay a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left:-50px;

}

.white-color-bg h2
{
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    
}

.white-color-bg h3
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    color: #e74c3c !important;


}
.white-color-bg h2, .white-color-bg h3
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 0;
}

.btn-profile
{
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 05px 20px;
    border-radius: 05px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    z-index: 3;
}

.btn-profile:hover
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color: #e74c3c; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
              <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2" >
              <div class="item-overlay right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-profile">visit profile</a>
              </div>
              <h2>Profile name</h2>
              <h3>Designation</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A little description of what the issue is an how this solves it would help the OP a lot more than just dumping code. Especially if the answer is identical to one already posted

Comment: Thank for reply Nitya. How can i display full image of circle?

Answer (score 0):

This is continuation to @RoryMcCrossan's answer. I just modified few `bottom` css properties to show the full circular image. I hope you want it that way only:

Updated: to set `top:50px;` for overlay div.

```css
.white-color-bg {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.white-color-bg:hover .item-overlay.right {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top:50px;
}
.white-color-bg:hover h2,
.white-color-bg:hover h3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.teacher-circle img {
  width: 135px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /*bottom: 50px;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* fix text transition issue for .left and .right but need to overwrite left and right properties in .right */
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}
.item-overlay.right {
  right: 200%;
  left: -100%;
}
.item-overlay a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px; /* bottom: 30px;*/
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.white-color-bg h2 {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.white-color-bg h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 400;
  color: #e74c3c !important;
}
.white-color-bg h2,
.white-color-bg h3 {
  position: relative;
  /*bottom: 20px;*/
  line-height: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 0;
}
.btn-profile {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 05px 20px;
  border-radius: 05px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-profile:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="white-color-bg teacher-circle cursor-pointer">
        <img src="http://cdn.leanincircles.org/ui/modules/common/images/notification-icon.png?v=2">
        <div class="item-overlay right">
          <a href="#" class="btn-profile">visit profile</a>
        </div>
        <h2>Profile name</h2>
        <h3>Designation</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.VijayP, I have added one image in question.Please check that.I need like that.If i remove "overflow: hidden;" from ".white-color-bg" than it works but i don't want to remove that

Comment: @Hybreeder - can you check it now.